# Regex to match a series of numbers in a string delimited by \n (it's one string only)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to test a string (Javascript) (which is entered in a textarea). Something like this:

```
111-11111
22-2222
3333333-33
...
```

This is the expression that I used:

```
/(\d+-\d+\n*)+/
```

The idea is: The whole group of `\d+-\d+\n*` (which matched 111-11111\n) which has to be repeated at least one time

This works fine for string such as:

```
111-1111
```

or

```
111-1111\n
```

But whenever I tried:

```
111-1111
222
```

It's passed too, which it's wrong.

How can I correct this?

Comment: Do you want your regex to give you 3 matches for the text containing the `111-11111\n22-2222\n3333333-33`? That would be achievable by doing `\d+-\d+`

Comment: Cannot reproduce https://regex101.com/r/XY12iu/1

Comment: A simple `preg_match_all('/\d+-\d+/', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);` should do the trick.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for @Hoang Trinh ? https://regex101.com/r/D9wPOb/1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single dash phone number - regex validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574911/single-dash-phone-number-regex-validation)

Comment: Thank you guys. But I mean the string "111-111\n222-222" should match. But the string "111-111\n222" should NOT match. It's not 2 strings but 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a regex like this:

```
(\d+-\d+\s*)+(?![\s\S])
```

[**[Regex Demo ]**](https://regex101.com/r/XY12iu/2)

That will not accept any other characters after your pattern.

> Note:
>
> - I use `\s` that will cover any white-space character like `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, . you can use `\n` to be more strict about it or `[\n\r]`.
> - `[\s\S]` will cover any kind of characters involving white-space characters and non-white-space characters.
> - `(?!)` is a negative look ahead that will check forward that not contains your criteria.

Comment: Thank you very much, this expression is exactly what I need. ^.^ Can you please explain this part `(?![\s\S])`? And why there is no `\n` in this expression but it still works? Thank you.

Comment: I add a Note about them -HTH ;).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
/\d+-\d+\n*/g
```

Comment: Thank you. But this still lets the string "1233-456\n111" passed. Btw, what is the meaning of letter "g" at the end? I thought the expression is supposed to be inside of /.../ ?

Comment: letter "g" means it will search this pattern globally and I am assuming '\n' is a new line character, is that ok ?

Comment: Yes, \n is new line character. The problem is it should only let "1233-456\n111-222\n..." passed. Not "1233-456\n111". I want to find a way so that this pattern `\d+-\d+\n*` repeat over and over